# заполнить матрицу вводом с консоли Python

Tags: python

Сломал голову уже, никак не могу понять как делать
Вывести матрицу 1
На вход программе подаются два натуральных числа nn и mm, каждое на отдельной строке — количество строк и столбцов в матрице. Далее вводятся сами элементы матрицы — слова, каждое на отдельной строке; подряд идут элементы сначала первой строки, затем второй, и т.д.

Напишите программу, которая сначала считывает элементы матрицы один за другим, затем выводит их в виде матрицы.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подаются два числа nn и mm — количество строк и столбцов в матрице, далее идут n \times mn×m слов, каждое на отдельной строке.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести считанную матрицу, разделяя ее элементы одним пробелом.

Sample Input 1:

```
4
2
и
швец
и
жнец
и
на
дуде
игрец
```

Sample Output 1:

```
и швец
и жнец
и на
дуде игрец
```

```
n, m = int(input()), int(input())
matrix = []
for i in range(n):
   matrix = [input() for _ in range(m)]

print(matrix)
```

Comment: `matrix.append(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил в итоге так:

```
n, m = int(input()), int(input())
matrix = []
for i in range(n):
   matrix.append([input() for _ in range(m)])

for i in range(n):
   for j in range(m):
      print(matrix[i][j], end=' ')
   print()
```

Comment: Ну вот, можете же )

Answer (score 8):

**Чтобы заполнить и напечатать матрицу**

- Мы считываем и записываем размер матрицы в n, m
- Инициализируем саму матрицу
- Создаём цикл и записываем в матрицу строчки
- Последний пункт - выводим матрицу на экран

Таким образом у нас получается следующий код:

```
n, m = int(input()), int(input())
matrix = []
for i in range(n):
    matrix += [[input() for _ in range(m)]]

for line in matrix:
    print(*line)
```